# Movie where two people break into a high-tech safe in underwear because of some fuel pellets making it incredibly hot

Tags: story-identification, movie

A pair of travelers are walking through woody terrain covered in deep snow, well dressed for cold winter. They reach some sort of bunker and go inside. There it turns out they are a man and a woman. The man throws some hi-tech fuel pellets into the room that cause a lot of heat, which makes the red-hued interior unbearably warm. The purpose of the heat is probably to fool the heat sensors. The heat forces them to remove all their clothing except for the underwear, and to pour over themselves some liquid to cool off, could be champagne. The woman asks why he hadn't warned her about the heat, and the man replies that she wouldn't have believed him.

They are there to break a safe. The safe has a keypad with a lot of keys, maybe even 10x10=100 keys. The man presses some of the keys in the appropriate sequence and appropriate pattern, and the pressed keys are lit up.

That is all I remember. It's a thriller from the 70's, but with those high-tech pellets and unusual safe protection thing this movie could also pass for sci-fi in those days.

Comment: Assuming you are the same Dialecticus that asked this [on this forum](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2551169) back in 2016 have you ruled out [_A Fine Pair_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064329/) as was suggested there?

Comment: Haven't seen that answer before. How did you find it? Thanks BTW, I'll check it out, but judging by the IMDB comment that's the one!

Comment: I feel the question was asked in good faith, but the provided answer, which the querent has stated as correct, does not use science fiction aspects nor was the movie marketed as such.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots very true. I asked this question many years ago in [movies.se], and got no answer, and in the end got the question purged. Here I got the answer within an hour. I gather that this site has a proper audience for this movie, maybe because the movie has a few memorable elements that this audience appreciates. I got my answer, so I'm fine with any verdict from any authority. Just consider the upvotes..

Comment: I don't know why I used the "scientific solutions or explanations" close reason, however, Edlothiad and Skooba used the correct one of just "off topic" here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [*A Fine Pair*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064329/) (1968)

> A detective gets involved with the beautiful daughter of an old friend. The daughter turns out to be a jewel thief, who in turn gets the detective involved in a caper in Austria.

The following [review on IMDb by ksf-2](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw3585208/?ref_=tt_urv) matches part of what you remember:

> There is one titillating scene as Harmon must spray Esmerelda down with champagne, when the room temperature gets too hot. Esmerelda is only wearing her under-garments, due to the high temperature, of course!

The scene you remember, and the one in the review above, appears to start around 59 minutes into the film with the start being the pair walking through the snow. I'm not really sure why the two strip off and spray themselves down as I skimmed a none English dubbed version so didn't know what they were saying. However, when they regain their senses Esmerelda opens up the safe and finds this keypad on the inside which is similar to how you remember it. The only difference being is that Esmerelda opens it, not Mike.

[image: Keypad on the interior of the safe]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This image on IMDb (woman in underwear so hidden behind spoiler tags) is the scene where Esmerelda has been sprayed with champagne and is stealing some jewels from the safe.

> [image: Esmerelda in her underwear after being cooled off with champagne]
> <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

I found this by searching for `movie pellets make a lot of heat breaking a safe underwear` which returned this [Whirlpool forum page](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2551169) where a "Dialecticus" had asked the same/a similar question back in 2016. User MystMoonstruck replied that it sounded like *A Fine Pair*.

Comment: FWIW from scanning the dubbed version of this film it seems very odd to put it mildly.

Comment: Which does lead to the question... this doesn't seem like a science-fiction film. Was it marketed as one?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Doesn't appear like it, I suppose the film could potentially be one but I haven't seen it properly or an English language version to know for sure.